# Extension of Laplace Transform on negative half space

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform

I consider the Laplace transform of the function $f(t) = e^{at}$, $t\geq 0$ and $a$ is some constant.

It has the form
$$
\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}(s) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-s t} e^{a t} dt  = \frac{1}{s-a}
$$
and is well-defined for $Re(s)>a$.

I know from the general theory that the Laplace transform is well defined for $Re(s)>s_0$.
In our case $s_0 = a$.
Moreover, I know that in the region of the absolute convergence the Laplace transform is analytic.

In this particular example our Laplace transform is an analytic function not only for $Re(s)>a$, but also for $Re(s)<a$. It is only not defined when $s=a$.

I wonder if there exists a more general theorem which tells us under which conditions on $f(t)$ we can extend the Laplace transform on a negative half space and in this region it is also analytic.